# Split sparse matrices and put them back together

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to be able to split sparse scipy matrices apart and them put them back together.

For example, starting with sparse array:

```
# 0 1 0 
# 3 0 5
# 0 7 0
```

Split it into 6 sparse arrays:

```
# 0   1   0
# 3   0   5
#
# 0   7   0
```

In other words, I want functions split_sparse and merge_sparse such that following test passes:

```
# Humpty Dumpy sat on a wall
mat = np.arange(9)
mat[::2] = 0
mat=mat.reshape(3, 3)
mat=csr_matrix(mat)

# Humpy dumpty had a great fall
row_divs = [2]
col_divs = [1, 2]
split_mat = split_sparse(mat, row_divs, col_divs)

sparse_eq = lambda x, y: (x-y).nnz == 0

# All the kings horses and all the kings men
assert sparse_eq(split_mat[0, 0], csr_matrix([[0], [3]]))
assert sparse_eq(split_mat[0, 1], csr_matrix([[1], [0]]))
assert sparse_eq(split_mat[0, 2], csr_matrix([[0], [5]]))
assert sparse_eq(split_mat[1, 0], csr_matrix([[0]]))
assert sparse_eq(split_mat[1, 1], csr_matrix([[7]]))
assert sparse_eq(split_mat[1, 2], csr_matrix([[0]]))

# Pooled their efforts and put Humpy together again.
assert sparse_eq(merge_sparse(split_mat), mat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question as usual Peter.  Here is your answer.

Edit: As hpaulj pointed out, the solution has nothing to do with the arrays being sparse, it simply takes advantage of the fact that scipy already has efficient implementations of slicing, hstack, and vstack.

```
from scipy.sparse import hstack, vstack
import numpy as np


def split_sparse(mat, row_divs = [], col_divs = []):
    '''
    mat is a sparse matrix
    row_divs is a list of divisions between rows.  N row_divs will produce N+1 rows of sparse matrices
    col_divs is a list of divisions between cols.  N col_divs will produce N+1 cols of sparse matrices

    return a 2-D array of sparse matrices
    '''
    row_divs = [None]+row_divs+[None]
    col_divs = [None]+col_divs+[None]

    mat_of_mats = np.empty((len(row_divs)-1, len(col_divs)-1), dtype = type(mat))
    for i, (rs, re) in enumerate(zip(row_divs[:-1], row_divs[1:])):
        for j, (cs, ce) in enumerate(zip(col_divs[:-1], col_divs[1:])):
            mat_of_mats[i, j] = mat[rs:re, cs:ce]

    return mat_of_mats


def merge_sparse(mat_of_mats):
    '''
    mat_of_mats is a 2D array of sparse matrices where:
        mat_of_mats[i, j1].shape[0] == mat_of_mats[i, j2].shape[0] for any j1, j2
        mat_of_mats[i1, j].shape[1] == mat_of_mats[i2, j].shape[1] for any i1, i2
    i.e. They can be tiled together.

    Merge them together into a single sparse matrix.
    '''
    rows = [hstack(m) for m in mat_of_mats]
    newmat = vstack(rows)
    return newmat
```

Comment: With the appropriate `hstack` and `vstack` it looks like this would work with dense arrays as well.  It's taking advantage of the fact that certain sparse formats implement slicing and indexing nearly as well as dense arrays  (`mat[rs:re, cs:ce]`).